# How to add an event handler using reflection when do not have access to EventArgs type?

Tags: c#, .net, events, reflection, eventargs

I have the following code in one assembly:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    class InternalClass
    {
        public event EventHandler<MyArgs> MyEvent;

        public void RaiseMyEvent()
        {
            MyEvent(this, new MyArgs());
        }
    }

    class MyArgs : EventArgs
    {
    }
}
```

and the following code in another assembly:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\path\to\MyLibrary.dll");
            var types = assembly.GetTypes();
            var internalClassType = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName == "MyLibrary.InternalClass");
            var eventInfo = internalClassType.GetEvent("MyEvent");

            var internalClass = Activator.CreateInstance(internalClassType);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(internalClass,
                Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, typeof(Program), "MyHandler"));

            internalClassType.GetMethod("RaiseMyEvent").Invoke(internalClass, new object[0]);
        }

        public static void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following exception at `Delegate.CreateDelegate`: *Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.*

The types in the first assembly are internal and cannot be changed, nor grant friend assembly access to the second.

I tried to dynamically create a method via the following:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\path\to\MyLibrary.dll");
            var types = assembly.GetTypes();
            var internalClassType = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName == "MyLibrary.InternalClass");
            var myArgsType = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName == "MyLibrary.MyArgs");
            var eventInfo = internalClassType.GetEvent("MyEvent");

            var methodInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyHandler");
            var method = new DynamicMethod("MyHandlerImpl", null, new[] { typeof(object), myArgsType });
            var generator = method.GetILGenerator();
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            var internalClass = Activator.CreateInstance(internalClassType);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(internalClass, method.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType));

            internalClassType.GetMethod("RaiseMyEvent").Invoke(internalClass, new object[0]);
        }

        public static void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following exception at `MethodBase.Invoke`: *Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.MyHandlerImpl(System.Object, MyLibrary.MyArgs)' to access type 'MyLibrary.MyArgs' failed.*

Is there any way I can handle an event when I do not have access to the EventArgs type?

Comment: I learned something new. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out.

I changed

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("MyHandlerImpl", null, new[] { typeof(object), myArgsType });
```

to

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("MyHandlerImpl", null, new[] { typeof(object), typeof(EventArgs) });
```

and made the `Program` class public and everything worked.